# Include multiple conditions in an if statement without repeating

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write it so that the if statement executes if it is not null and not "". I know I can just do && then copy the same thing over and change the null to "" but is there a way to do something like:

```
!= null && ""
```

original if statement:

```
if(msg['component']['section']['entry']['code']['@code'].toString() != null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do a exclamation mark that will be true for null and an empty string

```
if(!msg['component']['section']['entry']['code']['@code'])
```

Comment: That poor `0` though that did not mean to appear falsey

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use a dummy variable to hold the value:

```js
var value = msg['component']['section']['entry']['code']['@code'].toString();
if (value != null && value != "") {
    // some logic here...
}
```

However, JavaScript supports the concepts of "truthy" or "falsy."  In this case, you might just be able to accept the following:

```js
if (msg['component']['section']['entry']['code']['@code'].toString()) {
    // logic
}
```

Comment: It will throw exception on `toString`, if any prop in chain will be `nullish`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in every place where `null` value can appear, you don't have to call it by `['...']` (unless object key is non-alphanumeric, like your `@code`), e.g. let's assume that every property in chain might be a `null` (bad practice, but sometimes can happen):

```js
if (
 msg?.component?.section?.entry?.code?.['@code']?.toString()
)
```

Above code will return `false` if any property in `chain` will be `null` (in fact `falsy`, but as I can see those all in chain needs to be objects, otherwise it wouldn't be any sens in it).

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) you have all `falsy` values in `JavaScript`.

Usually you need to be careful for `0`, but in your case, you are doing `toString()`, so you are fine with this.

### Alternate solution

If you have a lot of values and you want to check if any or every of them match condition, you can also use [Array.property.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [Array.property.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). e.g. :

```js
const randomArray = [{ x: 5 }, '', null, {y: 5}, 0]

// "!!" will cast "falsy" to "false" and any other to "true"
if (randomArray.every(e => !!e)) { 
  console.log('All items are not falsy')
}

if (randomArray.some(e => !e)) {
  console.log('There is at least 1 falsy element')
}

if (randomArray.some(e => e !== '' || e !== null)) { 
  console.log('There is at least 1 empty string or null')
}
```

Comment: `Optional chaining` is pretty common in every modern language. If you are adding a lot of old-school `if-null` checks (like in old java 8 times), I'm pretty concerned.

Comment: One could say that optional chaining of this depth implies that the developer has no idea of what's going on around them. I advocate optional chaining most definitely.

Comment: Optional chaining returns undefined if one of those doesn't exist. So this entire condition is true even if `msg` is undefined

Comment: Just realized it might work because of the loose check `!= null`. The condition is false for both undefined and null.